# C++ SQLite3 not deleting with prepared statement

Tags: c++, sqlite, prepared-statement

I have the following code in C++ to DELETE all ID's which are not in the vector IDs. The ID's that should be deleted are printed, however the DELETE seems to fail because of the ID-binding. (When I remove the ID from the statement and only bind the reference, it works well).

This is how the DB is created:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Files (
    ID LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    Reference LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    FilePath LONGTEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    ProcessedOn LONGTEXT NOT NULL)
```

The code to delete the right ID's:

```
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT ID FROM Files WHERE Reference=? AND ID IS NOT NULL", -1, &stmt, 0);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, Settings["Reference"].c_str(), Settings["Reference"].length(), 0);
CheckDBError(rc);
rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
sqlite3_stmt* stmt2;
int rc2 = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "DELETE FROM Files WHERE ID=? AND Reference=?", -1, &stmt2, 0);
CheckDBError(rc2);
while(rc == SQLITE_ROW) {
    string IDToCheck = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
    cout << "Checking: " << IDToCheck << endl;
    if (find(IDs.begin(), IDs.end(), IDToCheck) == IDs.end()) {
        cout << "Delete " << IDToCheck << endl;

        //SHOWS ME THE CORRECT ID's BUT THE DELETE IS NOT WORKING. THE 
        //STATEMENT IS EXECUTED PROPERLY WHEN I ONLY USE IT WITH BOUND
        //REFERENCE, SO BINDING the IDToCheck GOES WRONG?

        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt2, 1, IDToCheck.c_str(), IDToCheck.length(), 0);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt2, 1, Settings["Reference"].c_str(), Settings["Reference"].length(), 0);
        rc2 = sqlite3_step(stmt2);
        }
    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    }
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
sqlite3_finalize(stmt2);
```

Comment: "seems to fail" "is not working" Can you be more specific?

Comment: Well,  the record is not deleted. However, when I only bind the reference, so removing the ID=? from the statement, it deletes the records well. However, when I bind ID=? again than the statement is not deleting the records. **So in my opinion, the binding of ID fails**

Comment: Have you used your debugger to validate that you're passing the expected values to the `sqlite3_bind_text()` function?

Comment: @MrEricSir, Wauw you are opening worlds for me. Debugger? Tell me more.

Comment: What about `rc` and `rc2`? And read what the [sqlite3_bind_text() documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) has to say about its last parameter.

Comment: @CL., RC is the select query and RC2 is the delete query so thats correct? What do you mean with the last parameter?

Comment: If some step fails, you need to check the return value and log the corresponding error message. The last parameter must not be `0`.

Comment: @CL., what value should I use?

Comment: The correct one. What part of the documentation do you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sqlite3_bind_text() documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) says:

> The fifth argument to the BLOB and string binding interfaces is a destructor used to dispose of the BLOB or string after SQLite has finished with it. The destructor is called to dispose of the BLOB or string even if the call to bind API fails. If the fifth argument is the special value SQLITE_STATIC, then SQLite assumes that the information is in static, unmanaged space and does not need to be freed. If the fifth argument has the value SQLITE_TRANSIENT, then SQLite makes its own private copy of the data immediately, before the sqlite3_bind_*() routine returns.

You do not have a dynamic buffer that is freed with an explicit destructor, so you cannot use a function pointer.
The buffer returned by `c_str()` is not unmanaged, so you cannot use `SQLITE_STATIC`.
So you have to use `SQLITE_TRANSIENT`.

Also, you have to check for errors (check `rc2`, and call [sqlite3_errmsg()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html).

Also, you need to [reset](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html) the statement before you can execute it a second time.

Comment: If I add `SQLITE_TRANSIENT`, only the first delete statement is executed?

Comment: Huh? Why are you asking that? Is that something you have observed?

Comment: yes... I execute the application and now only the first delete statement is executed. However, when I bind the ID with `sqlite3_bind_int64` the same situation occurs, executing only the first delete statement

Comment: the reset statement seems to be the point. I added the reset line and now it works as expected! Thanks, you helped me out a lot!